# valiadate unique value using callback function in edit function in codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

in the edit form i m checking unique email , if user click submit button still it shows error meassage as  is not unique. though it is unique value
this is validation in controller

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','required|callback_check_email');
```

and the callback function

```
function check_email($email)
    { 
        $return_value = $this->user_model->check_email($email);
        if ($return_value)
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('check_email', 'Sorry, This email is already used by another user please select another one');
            return FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
```

and this is user model

```
function check_email($email)
    {
        $id=$this->session->userdata('id');
        $this->db->select('Email');
        $query = $this->db->get_where('users',array('id !=' => $id,'Email' => $email));
        return $query->row_array();;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','required|callback_check_email[email]');
```

Answer (score 0):

If check_email function is used only for validation you should add _ as name prefix to make it inaccessible for public access like a private function and it will not be served via a URL request :

```
public function _check_mail($email)
```

Call the validation function with an extra _ and email as parameter :

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','required|callback__check_email[email]');
```

and an extra _ for validation message too :

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('_check_email', 'Sorry, This email is already used by another user please select another one');
```